# lightgbm issue ValueError: Input numpy.ndarray or list must be 2 dimensional

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm

Problem

Build prediction accuracy model using lightgbm on New York Taxi Duration dataset. Problem is "ValueError: Input numpy.ndarray or list must be 2 dimensional" with lightgbm.predict() function and.  The y is one dimension. X_train has multiple features, all reduced via importance. To analyze this numpy.ndarray for 2 dimensions, do we need to view the lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train) data creation? When I tried dim(X_train), that didn't work. Is not the numpy.ndarray created in the lightgbm Dataset() function?

```
lgb.plot_importance(gbm, height=.5)
```

Therefore, what is the ValueError complaining as incorrect, the ndarray X_train? Is not that what the lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train) purpose is for? to create a correct ndarray X_train lgb.Dataset? I'm still not able to determine how to view the lgb.Dataset after it has been created by lightgbd.

Setup train/test via

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, y_train, test_size=0.40, random_state=22)
y_train = X_train["trip_duration"]
```

Set lightgbm parameters

```
X_train = X_train[['pickup_longitude', 'pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_latitude', 'trip_duration', 'direction', 'week', 'minute_oftheday']]
X_test = X_test[['pickup_longitude', 'pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_latitude', 'trip_duration', 'direction', 'week', 'minute_oftheday']]

lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train)
lgb_eval = lgb.Dataset(X_test, y_test, reference=lgb_train)
params =     {'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
              'objective': 'poisson',
              'num_leaves': 31,
              'min_data_in_leaf' : 5,
              'learning_rate': 0.05,
              'feature_fraction': 0.9,
              'n_estimators' : 1100,
              'max_bin' : 6000,
              'bagging_fraction' : 0.8,
              'bagging_freq' : 4,
              'bagging_seed' : 8,
              'feature_fraction_seed' : 8,
              'min_sum_hessian_in_leaf' : 11,
              'force_row_wise' : True
              }
```

trained model, so far everything working fine

```
gbm_model = lgb.train(params,
                lgb_train,
                num_boost_round=1000,
                valid_sets=[lgb_train, lgb_eval],
                valid_names=['train','valid']
   )
```

Setup lightgb predict invocation

```
y_pred = gbm_model.predict([[X_test]])
```

Error received on gbm_model,predict()

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[187], line 1
----> 1 y_pred = gbm_model.predict([[X_test]])

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py:3142, in Booster.predict(self, data, start_iteration, num_iteration, raw_score, pred_leaf, pred_contrib, data_has_header, is_reshape, **kwargs)
   3140     else:
   3141         num_iteration = -1
-> 3142 return predictor.predict(data, start_iteration, num_iteration,
   3143                          raw_score, pred_leaf, pred_contrib,
   3144                          data_has_header, is_reshape)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py:734, in _InnerPredictor.predict(self, data, start_iteration, num_iteration, raw_score, pred_leaf, pred_contrib, data_has_header, is_reshape)
    732     except BaseException:
    733         raise ValueError('Cannot convert data list to numpy array.')
--> 734     preds, nrow = self.__pred_for_np2d(data, start_iteration, num_iteration, predict_type)
    735 elif isinstance(data, dt_DataTable):
    736     preds, nrow = self.__pred_for_np2d(data.to_numpy(), start_iteration, num_iteration, predict_type)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py:775, in _InnerPredictor.__pred_for_np2d(self, mat, start_iteration, num_iteration, predict_type)
    773 """Predict for a 2-D numpy matrix."""
    774 if len(mat.shape) != 2:
--> 775     raise ValueError('Input numpy.ndarray or list must be 2 dimensional')
    777 def inner_predict(mat, start_iteration, num_iteration, predict_type, preds=None):
    778     if mat.dtype == np.float32 or mat.dtype == np.float64:

ValueError: Input numpy.ndarray or list must be 2 dimensional
```

Data for this lightgbm model: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmuMI.png) X_test, [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GawYq.png) X_train, [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzOLh.png) y_train [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqYtn.png) lgb.Dataset(X_train) via lgb.get[X] commands

[image: X_test]

[image: X_train]

[image: y_train]

[[image: DatasetX_train]

Comment: try ```y_pred = gbm_model.predict(X_test)```